# UI Suppression ON for Skype for Business 2015 client failed

Tags: sdk, skype, lync, skype-for-business

I need to test Lync SDK (2013) app with Skype UI suppression.

I tried all possible registry paths that can be googled
on Win 8.1 Pro 64 bit with SfB 2015 client and Skype UI is not suppressed after its restart.

Correct registry path should be
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync
with UISuppressionMode DWORD key = 1 (BTW, I can see path and key name in my Lync.exe)

What are the other requirements for suppression? Can local or global domain group policy affect UI suppression?

Windows and Office (with Skype) are activated.

LyncClient.GetClient() can't start host process (gives exception "Hos Process is not running").
When SfB is launched manually, it has normal UI and InSuppressedMode = false and State = SignedIn

SfB About window tells:
Microsoft Lync 2013 (15.0.4809.1000) MSO (15.0.4823.1000) 64 bit
Skype for Business 2015. MS Office  Professional Plus 2013

This is Skype Basic, BTW. I have same result with Skype for Business 2016 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong, correct registry path is HKCU